# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' unexpected end of file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a string

```
str="xx:mvt="this is the value""
```

While executing above string in a command( command $str ). Command is not accepting 'this is the value' as one value.

How to do this?

I wanted to replace ' character with \" to interpret special character. below is the code but getting above exception:

```
str=`sed "s/\"/\\\"/g" <<< "$str"`
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and format things up correctly - four leading spaces before the `str=` will help. I tried to edit but I couldn't work out what was StackOverflow formatting and what was yours. Note that `\"` should be enough to escape things, or mix `'` and `"` to avoid nesting.

Comment: @AnjanJana : Your line `str="xx:mvt="this is the value""` invokes a program named `is` with the two parameters _the_ and _value_, so unless you happen to have a program with this name in your path, you should have received an error message such as _is: not found_.

Answer (score 1):

The assign should be in form:

```
str='xx:mvt="this is the value"'
```

This will keep double quotes and assign string `xx:mvt="this is the value"` to the variable

Also the command (with `sed`) must be like:

```
str=`sed 's/\"/\\\"/g' <<< "$str"`
```

Comment: Something wrong with the command:
$ str=\`sed "s/\"/\\\"/g" <<< "$str"\`
-bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: str=`sed 's/\"/\\\"/g' <<< "$str"` this command is not working. unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: @Romeo Ninov , works $ str=\`sed 's/\"/\\\"/g' <<< "$str"\`  
$ echo $str   
xx:mvt=\"this is the value\"